# change forms action with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a form that its action was initially to refresh the page. but I need a button that will submit the data and change the form's action. I have tried using JavaScript below:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="post">
```

### Button

```
<input type="button" class="submit" value="Save" onchange="submitForm()" />
```

### JavaScript

```
function submitForm(){
    document.getElementById('form1').action = <?echo base_url().'index.php/folder/controller/controller_function/';?>;
    document.getElementById('form1').submit();
}
```

When I click the button, nothing happens. I have also tried using if/else statement in the form's action, but that too doesn't work:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="<?if(isset($_POST['saveButton'])){echo base_url().'index.php/folder/controller/controller_function/';} else{echo "";}?>" method="post">
```

Comment: You should probably use `onclick` on the button.

Comment: change button onchange attribute to onclick

Comment: you can also take a look at the "formaction" attribute in html5

Comment: omg,, of course, thanks alot everyone. i've changed my 'onchange' to 'onclick' and it worked perfectly. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the value in your JavaScript should be quoted, as it is a string:

```
function submitForm(){
    document.getElementById('form1').action = '<?echo base_url().'index.php/folder/controller/controller_function/';?>';
    document.getElementById('form1').submit();
}
```

Secondly, you're triggering the function on the `change` event of a button, which probably won't work because buttons do not change. Try binding to the `submit` event instead, on the form itself:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="post" onsubmit='submitForm();'>
```

But I'd do it in the JavaScript, using an event listener:

```
document.getElementById('form1').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.action = '<?echo base_url().'index.php/folder/controller/controller_function/';?>';
    this.submit();
}, false);
```

Comment: thank you. i've edited my code as you pointed, and it worked perfectly. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around the action as shown below:

```
  document.getElementById('form1').action = "<?echo base_url().'index.php/folder/controller/controller_function/';?>";
```

You also need onClick instead of onChange

Works fine for me with these 2 changes.